# Endpoints other than open requested but private key and certificate are not set

Tags: python, opc-ua

Endpoints other than open requested but private key and certificate are not set.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Projects\Python\OPC\OPCServer.py", line 40, in 
server.start()
File "D:\Projects\Python\OPC\venv\lib\site-packages\opcua\server\server.py", line 355, in start
raise exp
File "D:\Projects\Python\OPC\venv\lib\site-packages\opcua\server\server.py", line 352, in start
self.bserver.start()
File "D:\Projects\Python\OPC\venv\lib\site-packages\opcua\server\binary_server_asyncio.py", line 116, in start
self._server = self.loop.run_coro_and_wait(coro)
File "D:\Projects\Python\OPC\venv\lib\site-packages\opcua\common\utils.py", line 197, in run_coro_and_wait
return task.result()
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1505, in create_server
raise OSError(err.errno, 'error while attempting '
OSError: [Errno 10049] error while attempting to bind on address ('192.168.111.221', 4840): the requested address is not valid in its context

Comment: I am facing this error while writing OPC Server code in python

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
It's also best to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to enable others to help you.
That also shows what you have done so far and at which specific problem you are stuck.